# Redirect in web.config file based on URL

Tags: redirect

I've changed the file structure of my site to be one less directory level deep.

Thus, I want users hitting:

http://example.com/directory/theRest/of/the/path

to be redirected to:

http://example.com/theRest/of/the/path

Seems like a simple enough web.config, right?

**How do I parse the path to simply strip out the first directory and leave the rest untouched?**

I imagine that this web.config would exist in "/directory", but perhaps it may be better in in the root, which would match a pattern of "/directory" in the URL.

Below is what I have so far (which is probably wrong). Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
<rule name="Redirect to main site" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="true" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://example.com/ ????" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer to your question is the following code snippet:

```
<rule name="Redirect to main site" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(directory\/)(.*)$" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="/{R:2}" />
</rule>
```

I have separated the URL path into two parts (grouped by brackets). This allows us to extract the `directory` from the URL. `{R:2}` refers to `theRest/of/the/path` whereas `{R:1}` refers to first part of the URL path - in other words to `directory/`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response! It makes sense and should work, but it's not behaving as expected. I seem to have 3 problems: 1) It only matches if the url is set to something like "^.*$"   2) It seems the {R:x} values are always empty  3) It doesn't apply to subfolders

Comment: You're welcome! Please answer me two questions.
1) Which IIS Version are you using?
2) How do you test your rules?

Comment: 1) Running IIS 7  2) I edit the web.config, then hit various URLs. All are 404s, since the directories are not there, which is the reason for this rule to begin with.  Also, should the action be "Rewrite" or "Redirect" and should the nest be <rewrite><rules><rule>...etc., correct?

Comment: I believed I figured it out! 1) the web.config needed to be in the root and not in the "/directory" folder.  2) I had other rules in that web.config, so it looks like order matters. When I move your rule code first, it works.  3) I added a few other modifiers to your code: stopProcessing="true" (on the rule), ignoreCase="true" (on the match), redirectType="Permanent" (on the action). Thanks again!